# dynamic values from server in modal popup listbox using php ajax js. (tinymce-wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, tinymce

I am creating a wordpress plugin (using tinymce) wherein i have a button. on button click a popup modal appears with some listboxes. the values in the listboxes are expected to be received from the server.
so to achieve this 
i have a php file which makes connection with the database and fires the query that can give the result. From client side, i have a js file in which i am writing a ajax query to call the php function. 
So to achieve this i am writing a function that will fire an ajax query to php. The problem is i am not able to return the ajax response to the caller.

```
(function() {
tinymce.PluginManager.add('attach_thumbnail_button', function( editor, url ) {
    editor.addButton( 'attach_thumbnail_button', {
        title: 'Attach Thumbnail',
        text: 'Attach Thumbnail',
        onClick:    
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Add Thumbnail',

                body:[
                    {
                        type   : 'listbox',
                        name   : 'list_project',
                        label  : 'Project Name',
                        values: get_project_list(list_project),
                    },
                ],
                onsubmit: function(e){
                    displayThumbnail();

                }

            });         

    });
});
})();
function get_project_list(list_project){            
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: 'techpub/functions.php',
    success: function (response) {
        // i want to return the value in response as it will contain the values that i want to add in the list box. 
        //using return response; not giving me the desired result. the list box is empty.
    }       
});         
}

function displayThumbnail(){
// this function is of no importance here   
}
```

and the php file is as follows..

```
<?php
$myServer = "10.0.0.29";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"database", "UID"=>"app", "PWD"=>"app");

// Connect using SQL Server Authentication.  

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo);  

if ( $conn )  
{    //this is some query that will send values as response
 $query = "select column_name from table";
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query); 
 if ( $stmt )  
{  
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt))  
    {  
        echo $row ; 
    } 
}   
else   
{  
    echo "Error in statement execution.\n";  
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}  

}
else
{
echo "Connection not established";
die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't encoding in to a format that the AJAX would understand. For best results when transmitting arrays you would want to use json_encode.

So, taking your code and making minor modifications and using $tempArray as the variable to highlight what will be getting sent to the browser:

```
if ( $conn )  
{
 $query = "select column_name from table";
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query); 
 if ( $stmt )  
{
    /* If you are going to go through the results one by one */
    $tempArray = array();  
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt))  
    {  
        $tempArray[] = $row; 
    }
    /* Output the results */
    echo json_encode($tempArray);
}
```

Comment: the values in the tempArray are not populating in the list box in the modal popup on the browser.. 
    below function get_project_list has to return the ajax response to the listbox. alert(response) works fine but the list box is still empty.. 

 
 function get_project_list(){
 jQuery.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: 'techpub/modellist.php',
  success: function (response) {
   //tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent( response );
   alert(response);
   return response;
  }
  
 });